# JSONLINT: Parse error on string

Tags: json, jsonlint

I'm trying to verify the following JSON on www.jsonlint.com:
http://s2g.supsi.ch/hcd/test.json

If I copy and paste the text in jsonlint the JSON is verified. However if I enter the JSON URL (http://s2g.supsi.ch/hcd/test.json) to jsonlint I receive the following error:

```
Parse error on line 1:
^
Expecting '{', '['
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work. Could be the text encoding?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code which reads the URL:

```
    if (jsonVal.substring(0, 4).toLowerCase() === "http") 
      {
      $.post("proxy.php", {"url": jsonVal}, function (responseObj) 
        {
        $('#json_input').val(responseObj.content);
        validate();
        }, 'json');
```

Here is the issue:

- The response from the http://jsonlint.com/proxy.php server URL returns a bad status code rather than the content in question.